# Add params array of string to Datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview, extension-methods, parameters

I have different datagridview which have the 3 first columns identical. The other columns differ from one datagriview to another.
I have wrote an extension method that get as paraemeter params string array which represent the values of the other columns.
My code:

```
    public static void AddNewRow(this DataGridView datagridview, params string[] parameters)
    {
        datagridview.Rows.Add(" ", " ", "A", parameters);
    }
```

The columns of each datagridview is already defined. The code I wrote do not add each string parameter in each column respectively, is there a way to do it?
Currently, the 4th column get as value the entire params string array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is there a way to do it?

Sure there is. Here is one of the possible ways using one liner LINQ

```
public static void AddNewRow(this DataGridView datagridview, params string[] parameters)
{
    datagridview.Rows.Add(new[] { " ", " ", "A" }.Concat(parameters).ToArray());
}
```

Comment: Didn't think about `Concat`, nice suggestion. @ehh Note this still works if `parameters` is an `object[]` instead.

Answer (score 1):

The call to `DataGridView.Rows.Add` expects an object array, so in your case it considers `array[0] = string`, `array[1] = string`, `array[2] = string`, `array[3] = string[]`. You need to create an object array of your items to add to the row as follows:

```
public static void AddNewRow(this DataGridView datagridview, params string[] parameters)
{
    List<object> values = new List<object>() { " ", " ", "A" };
    values.AddRange(parameters);
    datagridview.Rows.Add(values.ToArray());
}
```

For more robustness, consider changing the `params` object type to `params object[] parameters` as well.